# Gulp-browserSync task only running once

Tags: javascript, gulp, browser-sync

I have browsersync set up with gulp, html and css reloading is working just fine, but I've got a problem with javascript. When i launch browser-sync task and change some js, it only works as intended once. I've set up everything according to [this](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-reload) official guide.

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/*/*.js', './app/*.js'])
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});

gulp.task('js-watch', ['js'], browserSync.reload);

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./app/"
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('app/styles/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch("app/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch(['./app/*/*.js', './app/*.js'], ['js-watch']);
});
```

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyC68.png)
So, when i first change some javascript, it gets changed and the page is reloaded as intended - js-watch task runs js task and then reloads the page. But on the next runs, only js task is run.

I was googling this for about 2 hours before i decided to ask a question, so i hope this is not a duplicate. But just in case, sorry.

Comment: try with `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` in 'js' task after `.dest()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `.pipe(browserSync.stream());` in '***js***' task after `.dest()`

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./app/*/*.js', './app/*.js'])
        .pipe(browserify())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});
```